# Question closed because it can't be answered by facts, experts?

Tags: discussion

my [last question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1450/why-is-christianity-the-only-true-religion) was closed because of following:

> We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion

But how should I have asked that question differently? Isn't almost everything open to debate and different arguments? Even inside of Christianity there are many different opinion.

Answer (score 14):

> Why is Christianity the only true religion?

Your post is one of those *extra*-topical questions I'm sure we'll see over and over to challenge …

***"How can you guys believe this stuff is Truth?"***

Simply stated, your question *outside* the purpose of this site. This is *not* what this site is about.

The scope and *purpose* of this site is to create a canon of knowledge *ABOUT* the subject of "Christianity". Obviously, we are not checking credentials at the door, but within the scope of *this* site, users generally do not expect to be challenged on their belief system and, frankly, asking them to justify their own existence is not the purpose of this site.

But let's dispel the notion that this has anything to do with the hot-button issues of "religion" or "freedom of speech" with a quick analogy — We have an [Apple site](http://askdifferent.com) for experts and enthusiast interested in Apple products. If somebody were to ask, *"Why do y'all think Apple is the best when so many more Windows and other users think otherwise…?"* — it would be closed as "not constructive". The whole issue is largely irrelevant in the context of *that* site.

**It's the same thing here.** That's how you build Q&A sites. That's how you form and preserve community.

So, to answer your question specifically…

> Isn't almost everything open to debate and different arguments?

No. In some *other* discussion or debate forum; maybe, where those issues are up for discussion… but this is *not* an open discussion forum. This is a tightly-scoped Q&A site to ask questions regarding the canons and teachings of Christian faith. That also includes good-faith questions about their Christian lifestyle where folks are trying to rectify their day-to-day issues with the ideals of those teachings.

We talk about building these sites for "experts" and "enthusiasts." But those terms also apply to "practitioners" and "supporters" and "believers" in the subjects these sites are set up for. If you're not a fan of Apple products, don't use that site. If you think video games are a big ol' waste of time, Gaming SE isn't going to hold your interest… and if you are not earnestly interested in the precepts being discussed here, without pretense, this site may not be for you.

Answer (score 10):

I do agree that the question as posed was confrontational, even on a Christianity site where most people are in fact likely to believe that Christianity is the 'only true religion'.

I personally would have NOT voted to close a question phrased like this:

> Do Christians believe that Christianity is the only true religion? Are there any scriptures to back this belief up?

It's not an obvious question - some religions believe that they are merely one (and presumably the best) of many ways to God. Bahai springs to mind, and I think there are others.

Comment: Except that asking for Scriptures is asking for something of a circular argument.

Comment: No, it's not. Maybe the Bible says that there are many ways to God? You don't know if you haven't read it.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey. "Scriptures" !== "Bible".

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I tried to give you the benefit of the doubt that the question was not meant to be offensive.  Also, I consider this a side issue since editing could have changed it to be a respectful question.  So, that wasn't really in *my* thinking when I VtC'ed that one.

The problem that I had with the question is that it was far, far too broad.  There was no good, solid answer to that question.

The closest I could come to even forming a decent answer for this would be citing a **huge** list of prophecies made in the Old Testament that were fulfilled in the New Testament (or in New Testament times).  The topic would cover the entire bible and a good majority of the prophecies made in the Old Testament (and a few in the New Testament).

Because of that, I voted to Close this.  I could not see this question leading to anything except **huge** answers, large debates, and extended discussions.

Answer (score 4):

Because quite simply, the question is rude, and not constructive.  There is no knowledge to be gained when answering that question, and your statement can be offensive to those of other faiths.  As Christians we should be respectful and understanding that others do not believe what we believe.

Comment: Isn't it offensive already to say that only you are right? How can asking the question "why" be more offensive, rude and not constructive?

Comment: The fact is... this type of question doesn't belong on the site.

Comment: @Sven If you want to start an argument, go to a discussion forum.  The internet abounds with them.  [Christianity.SE does not try to be all things to all people](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/6103/24204).