# How can this question be made more applicable to Christianity.SE?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-definition, close-reasons

I posted [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/15642/what-evidence-supports-the-truthfulness-of-christianity-over-and-above-that-whi) yesterday, and it was closed fairly shortly after.

The title is **What evidence supports the truthfulness of Christianity, over and above that which supports other religions?**, with a stress intended on the second part of the sentence.

There has been some brief debate in the comments as to how this is nearly a valid question, or at least of there being something of a valid question in it.

What I'm trying to get at is examples of factual bases Christianity has that other religions do not.

I'm not concerned with what beliefs are true, the Truth, nor any of the other examples of bad questions [here](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/777/off-topic-not-constructive-examples). My question I think is most aligned with the examples of factual questions [here](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/779/on-topic-and-constructive-examples). i.e. I'm asking for examples of factual evidence that supports Christianity and Christian beliefs, the kind of which Islam, Bahá'í, Scientology etc don't have.

If there is something of a valid question within my question, what is it and how best can it be put to be on topic on Christianity.SE?

Answer (score 3):

The question is too broad; you need to be more specific. I think you're looking for something like "is there extra-biblical evidence that Jesus rose from the dead?" It doesn't ask for opinions or personal interpretation; Christianity stands or falls on that question, so it would be factual evidence for (or against) Christianity.

We would be unable to speak for what evidence "Islam, Bahá'í, Scientology etc" have; they would have to speak for themselves, so the question shouldn't mention other religions at all.