# Are questions about why did God do X instead of Y on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

E.g. Why did God part the Red Sea instead of teleport the Israelites across?

Rather surprisingly to me, this isn't in the "[what topics can I ask about here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" page, but it's also not [listed as an off-topic question](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/777/off-topic-not-constructive-examples).

Comment: *Why did God part the Red Sea instead of teleport the Israelites across?*  My personal opinion, but plausible: So His act could be understood within the culture of that time, and then celebrated in the book of Exodus (whose kernel were written from the time of Moses, around 1200 BC) and in the book of Psalms written later (but still older than 500 BC) using the literary devices common to people of the time.  Otherwise, they wouldn't have the scientific vocabulary needed to understand and describe and thus less able to emotionally and intellectually process the significance of what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, questions that only God can answer are off topic.  We call those "Opinion Based" but we know they're not really "Opinion Based" they're just impossible to answer without actually being God.

Now, that being said, this question has a good answer, but it's about Biblical interpretation, which is different between Christian denominations solely because the authority of the interpretation is different (i.e. most Protestants and Catholics could have the same answer, but the authority by which the answer comes about differs, therefore the answers are going to phrased differently).

If you're not interested in Christian theological traditions, then maybe your question is better off asked on the Biblical Hermenuitics site or even the Judaism site.

If you want to ask a Bible question, and get a mostly Bible answer, ask it from a Reformed perspective, in that way *sola-scriptura* and the perspicuity of scripture (both Reformed  doctrines) will assist you in getting an answer and alleviate the pressure on a potential answerer who quotes St. Thomas Aquinas a lot.