# On-Topic and Constructive Examples

Tags: discussion, scope, site-definition

This post serves as a brief listing of on-topic and constructive question examples, for use by new users and particularly those whose questions have been closed for being too generally philosophical or sociological.

---

<sub>This post originated as a result of [suggestions for a FAQ rewrite](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/767/84).</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Questions about doctrine*

  These are questions that are specifically about doctrine or doctrinal tradition. These questions do not necessarily relate to the Bible, although the biblical texts may be used in the question or found in the answers.

  - ["Do Catholics view atheism as a sin?"](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4240/84)  (Catholicism question)
  - ["How does free will fit with the doctrine of predestination?"](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4236/84) (Calvinism question)
  - ["How do Young Earth Creationists explain the teeth of animals if there was no death before the fall?"](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/41712/21576)  (Young Earth Creationism question)
  - ["Do Jehovah's Witnesses use different language for theological reasons?"](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3348/21576) (Jehovah's Witness question)
- Doctrinal interpretation*

  These are questions specifically about the Bible and how the Bible is interpreted based on a given doctrinal/traditional viewpoint.  They may or may not be asking about that doctrine, specifically; however, they are seeking knowledge about the Bible or the understanding/application of the Bible from a given viewpoint.

  It is worth noting again that all biblical understanding comes from some particular viewpoint.  Any questions about the Bible must be asked in relation to a viewpoint.

  - ["What is the biblical basis for an old Earth?"](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/2926/84) (Old Earth Creationism viewpoint)
  - ["Why are wives considered the “weaker partner”? (1 Peter 3:7)"](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3558/84) (Protestant viewpoint)
  - ["How do Protestants interpret Matthew 16:13–20?"](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/14744/21576) (Protestant viewpoint)
  - ["On what do Mormons base their practice of proxy-baptisms on behalf of the dead?"](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4187/84)  (Latter Day Saints viewpoint)
- Factual questions

  These are questions regarding facts surrounding or about Christianity.  They can include historical facts or modern day facts.  However, the questions themselves are not necessarily about the doctrine or interpretation of the Bible.

  - ["What are the major differences between NASB and ESV?"](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4003/84)
  - ["Why was Martin Luther attempting to change the canon?"](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4474/84)
  - ["Are there Protestants in Italy today?"](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4454/84)
  - ["What is the purpose of minor basilicas?"](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4477/84)

* Note that while the question is not required to have the doctrine or doctrinal tradition in the title, it is recommended, and regardless it must specify one in the body of the question.

---

(This is community wiki--*please* edit this and add more examples!)

Comment: Is this used for anything anymore?

Comment: @Nathaniel It's linked from one of the main default close reasons.