# Shouldn't I ask philosophical questions on Christianity Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, scope

My last question (now deleted) was very unpopular, the main reason seeming to be that it was unclear as a Christianity question as it was about God being infinite and all good things being perfected endlessly in the being of God. I thought this was an accepted part of our faith...but, as it's not about anything Scripture, maybe it's not. My question is, if ( as suggested) that question was philosophical rather than Christian, is it best to ask questions about the Bible's text? Thanks- learning all the time (hopefully!)

Comment: This may help you: [Types of questions, or template questions, that the community generally finds acceptable.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3409/3961)

Answer (score 6):

No.  That's one of the standard close reasons.

> General philosophical or sociological questions are off-topic unless
>   clearly asking for a doctrinal answer.See: [On-topic and constructive
>   examples](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/779/on-topic-and-constructive-examples).

And covered ad-nauseum on Meta and in comments on tons of posts.

If you can frame them correctly, you can get away with asking how group X answers philosophical question Y.

See [Tips for editing a question to make it suitable for re-opening](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/tips-for-editing-a-question-to-make-it-suitable-for-re-opening)