# RFC: Replacing the Philosophical close reason

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I'd like to replace the current Philosophical/Sociological close reason with one that gets more at the meat of why we're closing the question and offers some help for what to do to fix the question:

> General philosophical or sociological questions are off-topic unless clearly asking for a doctrinal answer. See: [On-topic and constructive examples](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/779/on-topic-and-constructive-examples)
>
> Questions that could be answered from multiple Christian viewpoints are not allowed, unless specifically asking an [overview question](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/870/4)

The stats show we're tending to favor the "opinion based" close reason, so we might as well revamp the custom close reasons so they don't overlap with opinion based as much.

I'd hope this would fix the qualms of new users who just want to have a discussion about the Bible, but probably weren't expecting to read what Jimmy Akin said Aquinas said Augustine said Paul said.

---

In the end, I wound up replacing the Truth close reason rather than the Philosophical close reason.

Comment: I've always viewed the General Philosophy close reason to be rarely needed, but vital in explanation when used. There's questions that arise that Christians will talk a lot about (e.g. divine existence, theodicy), but often questions on those topics are not actually about Christianity. That said, I'd say a good portion of the General Philosophy questions can be re-scoped to be great Christianity questions. So I don't favor removing that close reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to replace the truth question close reason with Peter's new proposed text. I think I might prefer that more... the idea of "truth" questions still confuse newcomers, but Peter's new text is very clear.

Maybe this text:

> Questions that can be answered from multiple Christian viewpoints are not allowed. They must be edited to ask for one perspective, or to explicitly ask for [an overview of all Christian positions](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/870/4).

I think it could be good to have a link for "one perspective" but haven't found a good meta post. Suggestions welcome!

Comment: OK - I should have gone back and read chat, I think I'd rather replace the "Truth question" close reason with this too.