# To what extent are psychological questions regarding Christianity allowed?

Tags: discussion

I am not sure if the question that I have in mind would be appropriate for this Stack Exchange, because it deals with the psychology of Christian believers.

1. How do conversion narratives vary among the born-again Evangelical Christians, non-Evangelical Christians (yes, this is a sociological term), and Catholics in the United States?
2. How did the Puritan conversion narratives convey their beliefs?

The first question may not have a basis in reality, but the second question concerns with history, literature, and religion. Where do I ask a question regarding Puritan conversion narratives?

Comment: The questions sound very broad and open ended. Can you narrow it down to a particular puritan's conversion narrative perhaps?

Comment: I asked a question about psychology: [Has the impact of a practitioner's theological framework on pastoral counseling methodology been studied?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/15623/)

Answer (score 1):

I personally like both questions (having recently become an informal sociology/psychology student).

I agree with you that the second question will be better received. The first question has a few sticky issues:

1. It doesn't really seem to be about Christianity, per se. Any decent study on conversion narratives should include other faiths as well. However, I could see someone like George Barna researching this exclusively for Christianity. Whether any exist or not, I can't say.
2. Is this close to [Christian fiction/literature](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3444/is-christian-fiction-on-topic) or [Christian Culture](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1841/how-should-we-handle-questions-about-christian-culture), which has been received with mixed reviews? Well, kind of.
3. Ultimately, unless there already exists some really good research on this, the answers that come from this will be incomplete, entirely opinion based without sources, or require extensive research on the poster's part complete with examples of conversion narratives from all three groups.

For point one, I think we can simply dismiss that. We shouldn't turn down good questions because the necessary research for a good answer may not exist.

For point two, I think they are all three separate and distinct topics. You are wanting to examine psychology, culture is sociology, and fiction can been viewed as popular culture, a subset of sociology.

Point three is the problem. Questions are closed all the time because of notions about the kind of answers it will receive. But I say the benefits outweigh the risks in this case. It's not exactly a topic that will get a bunch of trolls drooling.

I say ask away.