# Why was one question closed and one not when they are similar?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

The following question was closed:

[Are people who "think a lot about" God, Jesus, right and wrong more likely to go to heaven?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/15986/are-people-who-think-a-lot-about-god-jesus-right-and-wrong-more-likely-to-go)

But another question, similar in form and content, has been left open for some time.

[Why is it hard for a rich man to go to heaven?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/14416/why-is-it-hard-for-a-rich-man-to-go-to-heaven)

Why was one question closed and the other not? Both of them were even written by the same person. Are there some subtle diffferences that I am missing?

Comment: I don't know what the people who actually voted think, but the closed question doesn't seem to ask about a belief that any particular Christian group actually holds.  The open question starts from a particular interpretation of the Bible that seems very natural--likely even.  Neither seems particularly thoroughly researched, however.

Comment: @JonEricson: Interesting answer. In both cases, they related to beliefs that I hold. But you seem to be saying that in one case, I "stumbled" on a belief that others hold, and in the other case I failed to do so (because in both cases it was accidental). So the two question contents are quite similar, but the contexts are a bit different.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what the people who actually voted think, but the closed question doesn't seem to ask about a belief that any particular Christian group actually holds. The open question starts from a particular interpretation of the Bible that seems very natural—likely even.

As far as the site is concerned, questions aren't about what individual Christians believe, but what some Christian group believes.  Individuals believe *all sorts* of things and it would be an impossible task to tackle questions about all the possible things that Christians might assert.  We are mostly interested in coherent systems of theology, so it's hard to know how to take a question that asserts that thinking a lot about God is somehow correlated to getting in heaven.  It just doesn't make any theological sense (even if it might make common sense).

It's even likely that taking on all systems of Christian theology might be [too much](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/888/914).  There are groups that think [Jesus wore pants](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/1282/did-jesus-wear-pants), was [buried in Japan](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4993/what-sects-believe-jesus-is-buried-in-japan) or did [not even exist](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/5170/914).  With such large variations in belief systems, it can be hard to make any sense out of answers unless the scope of the question is reduced to particular groups of Christians.

As always, don't forget that questions may always be opened *if* they are edited into a state where people are will to vote to reopen.  In this case, if you want to pursue the closed question further, I suggest doing some research to find out which (if any) system of theology has something meaningful to say about the question and scope it narrowly.

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with any of  the main sects so I ask questions based on the "Bible." Apparently the site (all of SE, not just Christianity) prefers questions that can be answered by the "literature." So in my case, I'm just flying "blind." I thought this was a "Bible study" site (about the Bible) when it is more a "theology" site (about who holds what beliefs).