# What is Christianity.SE?

Tags: discussion

This is an attempt to clarify what Christianity.SE is, as if it were to be a potential rewrite to the FAQ.  It is **NOT** an approved FAQ. In fact, I may be [probably am?] wrong.  I'm just trying to throw something out there to get some consensus about who and what we are, and what it is we might be.

Answer (score 3):

Christianity.SE is an academic forum for the dissemination of scholarly knowledge about the tradition, doctrine, and practice of [mainstream Christianity](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/884/what-is-mainstream-christianity)* as it has been practiced over the last two milennia and is practiced today.

It is a place

- to ask and answer questions about how recognized Christian groups have understood Christianity throughout the millenia
- to understand how Christians interpret and apply scripture, tradition, and reason to their daily experience
- to understand theological development and social implications of current and ancient practice
- to use scholarly analysis to identify how Christians "do" Christianity
- to improve your own understanding of Christianity by asking [good questions](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/690/what-makes-a-good-focused-question) and writing [well-sourced, dispassionate, academic answers](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/what-is-a-well-sourced-dispassionate-answer)

It is not

- [a ministry](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193/brothers-we-are-not-christians) or even religious in nature
- a place to proseltyze or otherwise "convert" others to "your" point of view
- a place to work out or explain "your" theology, spirituality, or [personal philosophy](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201/personal-viewpoints)
- a place to get personal pastoral advice. If "you" are an integral part of the question or the answer, please seek a pastor or priest.  We might be a spiritual Web.Md, but we definately aren't your local physician.
- a place to argue for the sake of argument

Like a good seminary, Christianity.SE is a place for unbiased, dispassionate, scholarly reflection, analysis, and understanding of what all kinds of Christians do.

*Note: Mainstream here is probably wider than you think.

Comment: Anonymous Downvoters - could you please give guidance as to how to make this better? Thanks!